# Pretty URLs for dynamically created product and pagination pages

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting

I want to make a simple WordPress plugin that dynamically generates a paginated listing of elements of an array and product pages for each element. It examines if the current URL contains the query string "product" and displays either the listing or a product page accordingly. I'm not sure if the examination of the URL is the right approach for my goal though.

The plugin consists of two files:

test.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Testproducts
Description: Testproducts...
Version: 1.0
Author: xxxx
*/

function my_custom_shortcode($atts) {

    ob_start();

    include 'embedprod.php';

    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('embedproducts', 'my_custom_shortcode');
```

and embedprod.php:

```
<?php
 // Products/fruits in stock
$fruits = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Cherry",
    "Date",
    "Fig",
    "Grape",
    "Kiwi",
    "Lemon",
    "Mango",
    "Orange",
    "Papaya",
    "Peach",
    "Pear",
    "Pineapple",
    "Plum",
    "Raspberry",
    "Strawberry",
    "Watermelon",
    "Blueberry",
    "Blackberry"
];

$total_results = count($fruits);
$items_per_page = 6;
$num_pages = ceil($total_results / $items_per_page);
$pagenum = isset($_GET['productpage']) ? intval($_GET['productpage']) : 1;
$start_index = ($pagenum - 1) * $items_per_page;
$end_index = min($pagenum * $items_per_page, $total_results);
?>

<div id="productcontainer">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['product'])) {
        
        $productname = $_GET['product'];

        $user_data = null;
        foreach ($fruits as $item) {
            if ($item === $productname) {
                $user_data = $item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($user_data !== null) {
            echo '<h1>' . $productname . ' is in stock</h1>';
        } else {
            echo '<h1>Product not in stock</h1>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h1>Products</h1>';

        echo '<ul>';
        for ($index = $start_index; $index < $end_index; $index++) {
            $fruit = $fruits[$index];
            $productLink = 'example.com/?product=' . urlencode($fruit);
            echo '<li><a href="' . $productLink . '">' . $fruit . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        // Pagination links
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
            $active = ($i == $pagenum) ? 'active' : '';
            echo '<div class="' . esc_attr($active) . ' page-numbers">
                <a class="" href="?productpage=' . esc_attr($i) . '">' . esc_html($i) . '</a>
            </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to make the URLs "pretty" instead of query strings for the dynamic pages. Both for the pagination pages and the product pages. I was playing around with rewrite rules for days but nothing worked as I expected.

I know, I could have done it better, I could do it with wordpress functions, but I'm not an expert, I wanted a quick solution and it works as a starting point.